# Node.js: object is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I have just started working with Nodejs and trying to create my first node (using express)application. I am getting an error "TypeError: object is not a function" with below message:

```
/home/sears/workspace/Express/server.js:38
require('./app/routes.js')(app,passport);
                      ^
TypeError: object is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sears/workspace/Express/server.js:38:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:929:3
```

My server.js is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./app/config/database.js');
var mysqlDB = require('mysql');

// Config

mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

// require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
    secret : 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

// routes

require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

// launch
app.listen(port);
console.log("The magic is happening on port " + port);
```

I have explored other questions on SO with similar error messages and tried out things but without help.
What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: We will have to see your project structure and `routes.js` file. There is nothing wrong with `server.js`, only potential errors are wrong path to file or not doing `module.exports` correctly.

Comment: Please let us see the code in `routes.js`. do you write like this: `exports = function(app, passport){}`

Comment: I am able to solve it. There was an issue with routes.js file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with my routes.js which was not completed properly.
After doing that I am able to resolve the issue.